# Creating a loop with a Scanner

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to make it so a scanner takes in the number the user enters then prints hello world for how many times the user has imputed that number using a while loop. I created a Scanner for x, I am having trouble finding out how to properly execute the loop though.

```
// import Scanner to take in number user imputs
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // create a scanner class that takes in users number
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a whole number: " );
        // use x as the number the user entered
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        while ( ){
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a whole number: " );
        // use x as the number the user entered
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        while (x > 0){
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
           x--;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a `for` loop:

```
int x = scan.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

If you absolutely have to use a `while` loop, you can simulate the same behavior by declaring a counter variable (`i`, in this case) yourself:

```
int x = scan.nextInt();
int i = 0;
while (i < x);
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to define a true conditon in while.

```
 while (x > 0)//true condition.
```

How many time will you like to print your print statement.

```
 x--;//decrements the value by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
for(int counter = 0 ; counter < x ; counter++) {
   System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

The part reading `x` is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop such as the following one:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = scanner.nextInt();
while (x > 0){
    // do something
    x--;
}
```

Alternatively you could also use a `for` loop; this is usually the best choice if you know how often the loop will be called before it starts.